# Mysql Server, with Mariadb Slaves, disk usage high and many binlog files

Tags: database, mariadb, mysql-replication, database-replication

I have a Mysql Master server and a few MariaDB slaves connected to it. I have an issue in that my disk usage on the slaves have gone a bit mad.
My master server is 163GB with bin log files of 100Mb each ranging from bin.001260 to  bin.001357.

On my slaves I am using 294GB with my bin logs file of around 1.1GB each ranging from bin.000001 to bin.000208.

Is the fact that the names are not consistent a problem?  How do I go about freeing up the space on the slaves?
My expire_logs_days        = 10 days
but the binlogs on the slaves go back a few months for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check `server_id` on each machine (in my.cnf).  If they are the same, the data is going round and round forever.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I could just delete the old files that have already been processed. For some reason the max_expire logs doesn't seem to be working as I expected.

There are no duplicate ID's on the servers. No adverse effects on my setup after manually deleting the old files